# How to prevent users from spending time on edit-pages that will fail due to permissions?

Tags: apex, visualforce, permissions

I know how to restrict users and profiles from accessing Visualforce pages at all.
But there are cases where a profile is generally allowed to use a page but a specific user might fail to perform an action due to complex permission settings (MDR, child objects, ...)

I have a page where users will spend a lot of time before clicking Save the first time and then learn that they are not allowed to do this.

What is the best way to check this as soon as they go on this page?

I thought of using the `<apex:page action="">` attribute. Is that a feasible way?

Comment: Is this a native or Visualforce page or both?

Comment: This is a Visualforce page with a custom controller extension.

Answer (score 6):

If you are editing an existing record, you can use the [UserRecordAccess](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm) object to see a user's permissions to that record. In your extension constructor, query the record's permissions to see what access the user has to that specific record.

Comment: There is no need to query this. It's in the Schema objects.

Comment: You have to query it for existing records. The schema just tells you whether or not the user generally has permissions. Ownership and sharing rules can impact which records a user can edit.

Answer (score 0):

I ended adding an Apex-only based check to my controller's constructor

```
private void checkPermissions() {
    if(!Schema.sObjectType.MyObject__c.isUpdateable() && ...) {
        Utils.showMessage(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'You have insufficient privileges. Please contact an Administrator.');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd go with `||`, not `&&` :P And while it's good idea to have some checks server-side, you can use `{!$ObjectType.objectname.accessible}`, `{!$ObjectType.objectname.createable}` in pure VF to control `<apex:pageMessage rendered` or `<apex:commandButton disabled` too.